# How to revert files with specific extension in svn?

Tags: svn, file, revert

I would like to do something like this:

`svn revert --recursive mydata/*/*.txt`

and I want it to revert all files which have extension *.txt in the directory mydata. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On a POSIX-compatible OS (Linux/Mac/Cygwin):

```
find mydata -mindepth 2 -name \*.txt | xargs svn revert
```

[On Windows](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html) (use %%G in a batch file, %G on the command line):

```
FOR /R mydata %G IN (*.txt) DO svn revert "%G"
```

Strictly speaking, the Windows command will affect `mydata/*.txt`, `mydata/*/*.txt`, `mydata/*/*/*.txt`, and so on, so maybe it's not exactly what you're looking for... but maybe it's enough to get you there.

Comment: I doing it from perl, so yeah - I can iterate through files myself, but I was wondering if there is a way to do that in a single svn command.

Comment: This is not tagged as "only works on linux and mac" but it only works on linux and mac. Sadly there does not appear to be a way on Windows?

Comment: I amended the answer to add a possible solution for Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Linux or some other Unix variant which supports `find`? (Heck, it would probably be fine in cygwin too.) If so, try this:

```
svn revert `find mydata -name '*.txt'`
```

If you've got a *lot* of files you may need to use `xargs` instead.